# Why in C# we can't evaluate methods in ternary operator?

Tags: c#

I'm trying execute next code, but in C# it doesn't allowed. Why?
In C++ it works just fine..

```
void A()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
}

void B()
{
    Console.WriteLine("B");
}

void C()
{
    //getRandomInt return digit from 0 to 99
    bool compareResult= getRandomInt(100) < 50;
    var result = compareResult ? A : B;
    result();
}
```

Comment: What does `void` return or evaluate to?

Comment: C# and C++ are completely different languages. The fact that something works in one doesn't means anything about the other, despite the similar syntax.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp  the result of this expression is not pointer to fuction with type void without args?

Comment: @Alejandro this is obvious. But what the difference?

Comment: `var result = compareResult ? (Action)A : B;`. You just need to cast to `Action`.

Comment: The whole idea of C# was to *not* copy the bad features of C++. However, in this case the problem really is that the error message is not very clear. Sorry about that. I meant to fix it and did not get around to it.

Answer (score 6):

The error message is telling you there's "no implicit conversion between method group and method group". In the immemorial tradition of compiler errors, this has virtually no meaning in any known natural language. With experience, however, we learn that it's telling us we need to cast to something else, and we also know from experience that C# is difficult with us about implicit casts of references to methods unless the reference is typed as `Action` or `Func`. This is a crude and empirical rule of thumb which I find helps me get on with my life very quickly when I run into these things. There's value in a full and proper understanding of why this is the way it is; see below for some insights into that.

A and B are nonary methods returning void, so I tried casting to `Action`. It compiled.

```
var result = compareResult ? (Action)A : B;
```

The estimable Eric Lippert (see his entire series of comments below) clarifies:

> ...method groups do not have a type in C#; they are *convertible* to certain types, but they do not *have* a type

And when we say "method" group, we mean something like "referring to a function by name without calling it". Consider:

```
public void A() { }

public int A(int x) => 2 * x;

public void B() { }
```

There's more than one `A`. The compiler might be able to resolve the ambiguity on its own by taking the one that looks like B, if any of them do, but it doesn't, and from experience, I there are good reasons why it doesn't try to do that, which Eric addresses:

> the short version is: solving that problem is too much work for too little gain, and we're too likely to get it wrong. The slightly longer version is: we decided that in C# the only way to resolve a method group is to evaluate the member of the group for their fitness with respect to a set of arguments, either in the form of expressions when the method group is called, or in the form of types when the method group is converted to a delegate. There are no arguments available in this example!
>
> But when you include a cast to (Action) as you suggested, suddenly there are arguments available, namely, an empty argument list. Now we have evidence for which method in the group that the developer would like to choose: the one which has no arguments.

Comment: This nicely illustrates how poor error message design leads to user confusion. The real error here is: the result of the `?:` operator must have a type, and it must be the best possible type given the types of the consequence and alternative branches, but method groups do not have a type in C#; they are *convertible* to certain types, but they do not *have* a type. The error message should say "no best type can be determined for the `?:` operator because the consequence and alternative branches have no type; try inserting a cast". Regrettably, I never managed to fix that one.

Comment: This may be the first time I've been characterized as redoubtable. :-)

Comment: To answer your implied question in your final sentence, yes, there are good reasons; the short version is: solving that problem is too much work for too little gain, and we're too likely to get it wrong. The slightly longer version is: we decided that in C# the only way to resolve a method group is to evaluate the member of the group for their fitness with respect to a set of *arguments*, either in the form of expressions when the method group is called, or in the form of types when the method group is converted to a delegate. There are no arguments available in this example!

Comment: But when you include a cast to `(Action)` as you suggested, suddenly there are arguments available, namely, an empty argument list. Now we have evidence for which method in the group that the developer would like to choose: the one which has no arguments.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you. I was curious why the compiler allowed me to cast only one of the two method groups. "Redoubtable" turns out to be a little more adversarial than I had in mind -- I didn't mean to suggest you were fearsome or alarming!

Comment: When I worked on the VSTO team I was once waiting for my carpool to pick me up in the inky shadows of the parking garage wearing a black duster, black gloves, black pants and black shoes, and I must have accidentally startled my product unit manager on her way to her car, who said "well don't you look menacing". I think she was kidding but I felt bad about it; it was certainly not my intention to look menacing! I was just trying to stay out of the rain.