# Implement extension on a method (as if it was an action)

Tags: c#, functional-programming, extension-methods, func

I want to implement a loop on method with no parameters in just one line of code, instead of using `while(true) Loop();`

Basically I'd like to have this:

```
public void StartLoop_InOneLine() => LoopMethod().Loop(FuncBoolToStopLoop());
```

or this

```
public void StartLoop_InOneLine() => LoopMethod.Loop(FuncBoolToStopLoop());
```

To achieve the above I managed to create an extension but it works only if I convert the methods into delegates.

### Extension

```
public static class LoopExtensions
        {
            public static void Loop(this Action method, Func<bool> loopUntil)
            {
                while(loopUntil.Invoke())
                method.Invoke();
            }
        }
```

I would like to understand if and how I could achieve the above to further implement this pattern.

### Class Example

```
public class Looping
    {
        //what I would like to do
        public void StartLoop_InOneLine() => LoopMethod().Loop(FuncBoolToStopLoop());

        //what I want to achieve, in practice
        public void StartLoop_InPractice()
        {
            Action method = LoopMethod;
            Func<bool> loopUntil = FuncBoolToStopLoop;

            method.Loop(loopUntil);
        }

        private void LoopMethod(){}

        private bool FuncBoolToStopLoop() => true;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You're solution looks way more complicated than just using a `while` statement.

Comment: "it works only if I convert the methods into delegates" -- that's correct. `LoopMethod` is a "method group"; it might have overloads. The compiler will only attempt to pick a specific `LoopMethod` if you tell it what arguments are expected from the one you want. Casting to `Action` has that effect, so does assigning to an `Action` as you did. Also, kind of o/t, but `while(loopUntil())` will work in your extension -- no need for `.Invoke()`.

Comment: See comments on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010639/424129) for some observations by a guy who has been on the C# compiler team. BTW, I think your idea here is clever and pretty neat, but unfortunately I don't think it's going to be too practical.

Comment: It's more complicated if I we think as OOP. If we want to use FP it has more sense, at least I want to experiment with it. It would make the style more similar to LINQ. I do not want just to use this pattern here but also in other places. This is just the basic example.
----------
Yes. I see that this works.
`((Action) LoopMethod).Loop(FuncBoolToStopLoop);`
Is there any way I can remove the cast to Action?

Comment: Just read the answer you sent. So it seems there's no way to remove the cast.